# Can (javascript) widgets created for iBooks Author use SQLite (HTML5 web) databases?

Tags: sqlite, widget, ibook-author

I'm creating a "quiz" widget for iBooks Author and would like the widget to save student responses in a SQLite database in the iBook when the user is not online until the user can get an internet connection.

Is SQLite CRUD possible within iBooks? Does an iBook widget have those capabilities like Safari/Webkit? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about full SQL CRUD type storage, but if you have a look at the example widgets available at https://github.com/widged/iBook-widgets/tree/master/widgets you can see that there is a localStorage.wdgt, which shows that you can save data.

That might have you achieve what you're after.